# Am getting duplicate data from get_posts()

Tags: posts, theme-development

Am trying to display posts only from the "latest" category on my wordpress blog but am strangely getting the same post displayed twice. What am i doing wrong?
[image]

```
/*
* Theme file:index.php
*/
    global $post;
    $categories=get_categories();
    foreach($categories as $categories_item)
    {
        if(strcasecmp($categories_item->name, 'latest') == 0)//case-insensitive string comparison
        {
            $args = array(
            'numberposts'     => 2,
            'category'        => $categories_item->cat_ID,
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            'order'           => 'ASC',
            'post_status'     => 'publish'
            );
                $latest_stuff = get_posts( $args );
                echo "<h2>Latest stuff</h2>";
                foreach($latest_stuff as $latest_stuff_item)
                {
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    echo "<div>".the_content()."<div><hr>";
                }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the post posted on multiple categories?

Comment: try to deactivate all plugins to eliminate that influence.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the database data (posts, inherits, etc), it's a bit of guesswork.

Try the following:

- Make sure you have `"post_type"=>"post"` specified, so that you don't get auto-saved inherits (if it defaults to 'any').
- If this is an isolated query (not meant to be main loop), use $q = new WP_Query() and run it through that instead of get_posts().
- What does setup_postdata do? Does it accidentally rewind anything?
- Try escaping the category loop and apply `get_category_by_slug('latest')` to "category" (it returns an object with ID) to the call.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was WPML returning both languages. The solution to that was [suppress_filter in the WP_Query](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/wp_query-returns-posts-in-all-languages-rather-than-current-one/).

```php
$args = array(
  ...
  'suppress_filters' => false
  ...
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `echo the_content();`.

This is causing the looped output to appear outside the loop. If you change `the_content()` to `get_the_content()` this will work.

Note you might need to pass through the ID into `get_the_content()` by using `$latest_stuff_item->ID`

```
foreach($latest_stuff as $latest_stuff_item)
{
  setup_postdata($post);
  echo "<div>".get_the_content()."<div><hr>";
}
```